# .Net MVC 4 Home/Index URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I define that the starting URL in the MVC4 app is **server:port/Home/Index** instead of **server:port**

Edit: I think I didn´t explain well the question. I want that when I hit Run in VS the url in the browser be **server:port/Home/Index** instead of **server:port**. And I someone writes **server:port** in the url redirect to **server:port/Home/Index**

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should read about mvc routing. Come back here if you get stuck

Comment: I know, I have only expected a quick answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the project Properties, go to the "Web" tab and look at the options available in the "Start Action" - it sounds like you want to be setting the "Start URL" setting. Alternately the combination of the "Servers" section settings and the "Specific Page" option might work. (We usually use a combination of the local IIS "Project Url" and the "Specific Page" value.)

For the redirect part of the question there are several methods, and can be handled either in code or IIS. A quick search here should find some more complete answers.

Comment: Thank! Yes, the solution we will take involves handling this in IIS. But for local development it is the answer I was expecting. Will try it, thanks again!

Comment: I have seen that the "Start URL" gets stored in .suo or .user files and we don´t pull into version control those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch a great video series on MVC4 for free which includes routing. Scott Allan does a stellar job explaining the ins and outs of MVC.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4

The second section called 'Controllers' has a video called Controllers and Routing if you are in a hurry, but I would advise watching it all if you can find time.

Comment: Its 6 mins long and will explain what you want.